# Why does xargs skip first argument when passing to subshell?

Tags: shell, xargs

Looking for a way to invoke more than one command in a xargs one-liner, I found [the recommendation in findutils to invoke the shell from xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs.html) like this:

```
$ find ... | xargs sh -c 'command $@'
```

The funny thing is, if I use xargs like that, for some reason it skips the first argument:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs bash -c 'echo $@'
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ seq 10 | xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo $@'
2
4
6
8
10
```

Is something wrong with my shell or xargs version?
Is that documentation inaccurate?

<sub>Using **xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2** and **GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release**.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [bash] man page says: "*`-c string` If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to  the  positional  parameters,  starting with $0.*" - The key is *$0*; it means that the command name shall be the first argument.

```
seq 10 | xargs sh -c 'echo $@; echo $0' sh
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
sh
```

Answer (score 13):

> Why does xargs skip first argument when passing to subshell?

It doesn't.  Bash assigns the first argument to $0:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo $0'
1
3
5
7
9
```

`$@` expands to `$1` `$2` `$3` ....  Consequently, the value of `$0` is not included in `$@`.

Comment: This explanation is much clearer than @Janis's, but Janis's answer includes a good solution to the problem.